# Explict solution of a system of two equations mixing polynomials and logarithms

Tags: polynomials, logarithms

I'm struggling with a system of two equations, with two unknown variables $b$ and $p$ (the other variables, $r$ and $T$ are exogenous), mixing polynomials and logarithms:
$$
[1-2p+2bp-2b^2p]rT  
+b(1-2p)\ln\bigg[\frac{1-p}{1-(1-b)p}\bigg] 
+2b^2p \ln\bigg[\frac{bp}{[1-(1-b)p](1-e^{-rT})}\bigg] = 0 \\
(1-2 b)p r T+(1-p) \ln \left[\frac{1-p}{1-(1-b) p}\right]+2 b p\ln \left[\frac{b p}{[1-(1-b) p] \left(1-e^{-r T}\right)}\right]=0 $$
Approximations lead to a very nice shape of the solutions depending on $r$ and $T$, so there might be an explicit solution?...
Here are the conditions on the variables: $0<b<1;\quad 0<p<1; \quad 0<T;\quad 0<r$.

The system of euqations results from a maximization problem over $b$ and $p$ simultaneously:

$$
\max_{p,b} \pi^i(p,b) = \frac{p T}{n}\big[1-p+bp-b^2p\big]
+\frac{bp(1-p)}{nr}\ln\bigg[\frac{1-p}{1-(1-b)p}\bigg]+ \quad +\frac{b^2p^2}{nr} \cdot\ln\bigg[\frac{bp}{[1-(1-b)p](1-e^{-rT})}\bigg] 
$$

I would be very relieved to get some help about whether it is possible to get an explicit formula for $b$ and $p$, and if yes with which method. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have probably already noticed that $e_1-be_2$ takes away almost all of the $\ln$ contributions.  Since $b,p\in(0,1)$ you may be able to leverage a series expansion of $\ln$ out to just a few terms to get a pretty good approximation.

Comment: You mean like a Taylor series expansions? Thanks, I will have a look at it. Can I be so bold and just cut it arbitrarily?

Comment: Well, you can be bold if you use your limits on $b,p$ to prove that cutting off the series expansion does not lose significant value.